# How do I indent every line with a capital letter in vi with an ex command?

Tags: vi

How do I indent every line with a capital letter in vi with an ex command? The specific version I am using is elvis. I need to do this for a homework. I've searched help, but still trying to figure out how to navigate it. I'm using the US Constitution as the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the global command and a substitution command together:

```
:g/^[A-Z]/s/^/^I/
```

Here, the `^I` is obtained with [Control-V][TAB].